# Rebind an event handler that was unbound with .off() method jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element let's call it `div1` which I bind an event "click" to so it runs some code on click. 
Then I've got another element let's call it `div2` when it is clicked it runs this line of code: `div1.off('click');` So now the `div1` click event handler is unbinded successfully.

This works perfectly well however I would like to "rebind" this `div1` click event later on say on a third div click event.

I can't find anywhere how to rebind a click event which I called .off() on. 
Does anybody have any idea how I could accomplish this?

What I've tried:

```
div1.one('click',function() {
    ...some code
});
div2.on('click',function() {
    ...some code
    div1.off('click');
});   
//all good so far
div3.on('click',function() {
    ...some code
    div1.on('click'); //this is the part which is obviously wrong i just put it to show my intentions - this line needs to "rebind" the div1 click event
});
```

Comment: Add your `html` `css` `js` -> what you tried so far!

Comment: i edit my post. thanks

Answer (score 2):

You should create a function for your one click, for example `myfunc` your can rebind `div1` after you click on `div3`

```js
let div1 = $('#div1');
let div2 = $('#div2');
let div3 = $('#div3');

function myfunc() {
  alert('Haha!')
}

div1.one('click', myfunc);

div2.one('click', function() {
  console.log('off')
  div1.off('click', myfunc);
});
div3.one('click', function() {
  console.log('on')
  div1.on('click', myfunc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```

And here is example for use `bind` and `unbind` in this case:

```js
let div1 = $('#div1');
let div2 = $('#div2');
let div3 = $('#div3');

function myfunc() {
  alert('Haha!')
}

div1.one('click', myfunc);

div2.bind('click', function() {
  console.log('off')
  div1.unbind('click');
});
div3.bind('click', function() {
  console.log('on')
  div1.bind('click', myfunc);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1">div1</div>
<div id="div2">div2</div>
<div id="div3">div3</div>
```

Comment: this is a good solution, i was thinking of that but when i try it it runs the action twice since, its doing 2 clicks...any ideas? - thanks for your answer btw!

Comment: I think don't understand what you mean, can you explain more and clear? @UrielBitton

Comment: @UrielBitton it runs action twice? which one?

Comment: you see div3's click function, when you click on div3 it will run a click on div1 and then when i click div1 it will aso run its own functions. So the code inside div1 is run twice

Comment: @UrielBitton I see.. let me check

Comment: @UrielBitton One tricky solution is use `one` for all handler except rebind div1, Check answer updated

Comment: The intial div1 click will only work once. The unbind/rebind buttons will also only work once.

Comment: it doesn't work for me because i need to be able to click the other divs as many times as i want...

Comment: Can i send you a private link of my app so you can test it and maybe understand the problem better? Send me your email. thanks

Comment: @UrielBitton Is it web app? or ? I'm ios guy, but send me in chat

Comment: well its a web app based purely from jquery only. ill send you now

Comment: i can't chat with you, i think bc im a new user.

Comment: @UrielBitton wait

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205494/discussion-between-pedram-and-uriel-bitton).

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the anonymous function defined in div1.on to a normal function which can then be reused. As shown below -

```js
var div1 = $("#one")
var div2 = $("#two")
var div3 = $("#three")

div1.one('click',div1Click); //change anonymous function to normal function
div2.on('click',function() {
    console.log('2');
    div1.off('click');
});   
div3.on('click',function() {
    console.log('3');
    div1.on('click', div1Click); 
});    

function div1Click() {
   console.log('1');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">  
one
</div>
<div id="two">  
two
</div>
<div id="three">  
three
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of turning the click event on and off is to always leave the click capturing in place but make the action dependend on an extra `data` flag (here:`off`):

```js
$('div[id]').on('click',function() {
 let sw={two:true, three:""}[this.id];
 if (sw===undefined) { // div #one was clicked: do the action:
   if (!this.dataset.off) console.log(this.id); // do the action 
 }
 else $('div#one')[0].dataset.off=sw; // button #two or #three was clicked
});
```

```css
div {cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="one">one</div>
<div id="two">two</div>
<div id="three">three</div>
```

I tried a version with `{two:true, three:false}`, but, unfortunately, the variable `sw` is turned into a string when saved as `dataset.off`, so `false` becomes `"false"` and becomes *truthy*. A blank is always *falsey*.